# Reshaping an data frame in R

Tags: r, reshape

I have this data frame in long format in R which looks something like this..

```
Branch.Name Customer.ID Loan.Type Date      Stage       Time
           A    C001    Home      20/11/05  Processing  10
           A    C001    Home      20/11/05  Approval    30
           A    C001    Home      20/11/05  Finalize    5
           A    C002    Business  23/11/05  Processing  30
```

and I want to convert this into the wide format..

```
Branch.Name Customer.ID Loan.Type   Date     Processing Approval    Finalize
A           C001        Home        20/11/05    10        30        5
B           C002        Business    20/11/05    30        10        0
B           C003        Business    20/11/05    12        15        0
```

I looked at reshape and melt, but I got messed up answers...

Thanks in advance

P.S: Not all rows have "Processing", "Approval" and "Finalize" as stage, some may have extra stages

Comment: I think your `Branch.Name` in the input data should have `B'.  Perhaps `library(reshape2);dcast(df1, ...~Stage, value.var='Time', fill=0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a basic long to wide transformation.

Try one of the following:

```
## Base R
reshape(mydf, direction = "wide", 
        idvar = c("Branch.Name", "Customer.ID", "Loan.Type", "Date"), 
        timevar = "Stage")

## reshape2
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, Branch.Name + Customer.ID + Loan.Type + Date ~ Stage, value.var = "Time")
## dcast(mydf, ... ~ Stage, value.var = "Time")

## tidyr
library(tidyr)
spread(mydf, Stage, Time)
```